# How to (temporarily) prevent yum / dnf from updating repositories?

Tags: dnf

I sometimes face a problem that I only want to search or install a single tiny package and I am on a very limited internet connection (say: mobile data in a remote place abroad). Being more of an emergency case, I wouldn't mind using the cached repository contents; the last update would have been just a week or two ago. Yet `dnf` insists on downloading several MB of metadata which takes forever and which I don't want, and earlier today it happened that I was just rendered unable to finish a simple *search* operation due to this. I tried running the command offline but it refuses to operate if the metadata is not current. Is there an option forcing the command to use the old data, or a configuration entry to change the period for how long it is considered valid?

Comment: You download the specific `rpm`. However searching it in pages might mean (or not) more data than getting the metadata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in the various dnf and yum repo config files you should find several explicit metadata expiry times, eg:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo
  metadata_expire=6h

/etc/dnf/dnf.conf
  metadata_expire=86400
```

You can override these on the `dnf` command line using `--setopt=`, but you must explicitly do it for every enabled repository, as well as the dnf main configuration. So you end up with something like

```
sudo dnf --setopt=metadata_expire=-1 \
 --setopt=fedora.metadata_expire=-1 \
 --setopt=fedora-update.metadata_expire=-1 \
 --setopt=rpmfusion-free.metadata_expire=-1 \
 search abcdef
```

Note the use of sudo to avoid dnf creating a separate cache for the user.

Comment: You can also set this to a short value (i.e., 1m ) to force the cache to be dumped quickly, thought there may be other more elegant ways to do that.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is a little old (and this option might be new) but this just worked for me:

```
 -C, --cacheonly
              Run entirely from system cache, don't update the cache and use it even in case it is expired.
```

So `dnf -C install ...` worked for me

p.s. in my case I was installing RPMs that I downloaded elsewhere and transferred over sneakernet because my networking is busted and I did not want to subvert `dnf` by installing directly with the `rpm` executable

Answer (score 1):

It's not temporary, but it is reversible.

`sudo zypper modifyrepo --no-refresh --all`

or

`sudo zypper modifyrepo --no-refresh --remote`

You can manually refresh, when you have the data to spare with

`sudo zypper refresh`

This will also turn off refresh for the repos when using the GUI.

You can also control them in the GUI with the Repositories option in YAST, but that will do refresh, unless already turned off, when first launched.